# Automatic cleanup of Bash history

Tags: bash, command-history

How can Bash history be automatically cleaned up? For example

- Remove detectable typos from history (`ls-lh` does not show up in `which`, so it is removed, I meant to type `ls -lh`)
- Clean excessive spaces `cd  /` and `cd /`    should be normalized so they are the same.

Can this be done in bash? Maybe a filter on all commands before they are executed, or before they go into history?

I hope I don't have to wait until it is written to the file before running a cleanup routine. That would mean logging out before cleanup occurs. `:(`

Answer (score 1):

i would prefer to keep alias to all common mistakes that happen example

`alias ls-lh = ls -lh`

Use alias to fix missing space typos:

`alias cd..='cd ..`

Use HISTIGNORE to specify all the commands that you want to ignore from the history. use `export HISTIGNORE="$LIST"` to list that you want to ignore inside history

There are several other options of interest controlled by the built-in 'shopt' command.

see [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/08/15-examples-to-master-linux-command-line-history/)

Comment: +1 for using bash aliases. Also a good tip for keeping the history cleaner is using `export HISTCONTROL="ignoredups"` to prevent duplicates of commands.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any way to customize history beyond the few `HIST…` variables. You may want to switch to zsh, which is a little smarter (but only a little). In zsh, you can turn on command autocorrection ([`setopt correct`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-CORRECT)), which will suggest a correction for some typos based on the available command names (e.g. on my system it offers to correct `sl` to `ls`, but doesn't do anything about `ls-lh`). Zsh's duplicate is smarter in that it detects non-consecutive duplicates (under [`setopt hist_ignore_all_dups`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-HIST_005fIGNORE_005fALL_005fDUPS)). Zsh doesn't do any whitespace normalization in the history, but the completion system is a little smarter than bash's at keeping the amount of whitespace consistent whether you type a full name or hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, which helps.

Answer (score 0):

From [this blog](http://blog.dhampir.no/content/avoiding-invalid-commands-in-bash-history), this script can remove **automatically** all commands that are not found by bash.

If you don't already have a bash `PROMPT_COMMAND`, add this to `.bashrc`:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="mypromptcommand"
function mypromptcommand {
}
```

That function will now be run every time your prompt is about to appear. Within it, we put this:

```
local exit_status=$?
# If the exit status was 127, the command was not found. Let's remove it from history
local number=$(history | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $1}')
if [ -n "$number" ]; then
    if [ $exit_status -eq 127 ] && ([ -z $HISTLASTENTRY ] || [ $HISTLASTENTRY -lt $number ]); then
        history -d $number
    else
        HISTLASTENTRY=$number
    fi
fi
```

[The link](http://blog.dhampir.no/content/avoiding-invalid-commands-in-bash-history) provides the explanation of how it works